Green's function and Dirac delta property
I have a general confusion and question about Green's function and the Dirac delta property. Specifically consider $L u (x) = f(x)$ on $(0,1)$ with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$, where $L$ is a second order linear, self-adjoint differential operator. We can represent the solution using Green's function $G(x,y)$ as
$$u(x) = \int_0^1 G(x,y) f(y) dy \tag{1}$$
The Green's function is defined as follows: for fixed $y \in (0,1)$
$$
\begin{cases}
L_x G(x,y) = \delta_y(x) \qquad x\in (0,1)
\\
G(0,y) = G(1,y) = 0
\end{cases}
\tag{2}
$$
where $\delta_y$ is the Dirac delta centered at $y$ and $L_x$ indicates that the differentiations are performed in the $x$-variable. Here I'm writing $\delta_y(x)$ as opposed to $\delta(x-y)$ on purpose as my question is regarding this. As far as I understand the equation in $(2)$ is understood in the weak sense, meaning that for any test function $\phi(x)$ (smooth and compactly supported in $(0,1)$)
$$\int_0^1 L_x G(x,y) \, \phi(x) dx = \phi(y) \tag{3}$$
where the left hand side is defined as $\langle L_x G(x,y), \phi(x) \rangle = \langle G(\cdot, y), L\phi \rangle$ and $y$ is fixed as before.
Now my confusion arises when using this property we try to show that $u$ defined by $(1)$ solves the ODE:
$$Lu(x) = \int_0^1 L_x G(x,y) f(y) dy \tag{4}$$
How is this equal to $f(x)$ if what we have is $(3)$? I thought this should follow from $(3)$ using the symmetry $G(x,y) = G(y,x)$ which implies that $L_x G(x,y) = L_y G(y,x)$, hence
$$Lu(x) = \int_0^1 L_yG(y,x) f(y) dy$$
This almost looks like $(3)$ as the integration is performed using the first variable, except we're working with the function $L_y G(y,x)$ which isn't equal to $L_x G (y,x)$, but rather $L_xG(x,y)$. So how to conclude that $u''(x) = f(x)$ from the defining equation $(3)$?

Use $(2)$ in the integrand of $(4)$. Also, note $G(x,y)=G(y,x)$ does not imply $L_xG(x,y)=L_yG(y,x)$.

My question is essentially how to use $(2)$ in $(4)$. Isn't $(2)$ defined/to be understood as $(3)$? If I formally substitute $\delta_y(x)$ in $(4)$, then I don't really understand the meaning of $\int_0^1 \delta_y(x) f(y) dy $. Because if I think of $\delta$ as a distribution then its definition is $\int_0^1 \delta_x(y) f(y) dy =f(x)$, which I'm fine with. How does one change $\delta_y(x)$ to $\delta_x(y)$?

@MS1234. Note that $\delta_x(y) = \delta(x-y) = \delta(y-x) = \delta_y(x)$.
